# Python Scraping, how to get text from this through BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

well here is my code to scrape text content from a site.... well it is working though i am not getting plane text only.... how to handle that

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize
def getArticle(url):
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        htmltext = br.open(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
        for tag in soup.findAll('span',{'itemprop':'articleBody'}):
                print tag.contents
```

for example when i scrape a site.
i get this output

"[u"\nIn Soviet Russia, it's the banks that pay customers' bills.\xa0Or, at least, one might.", 
, u'\n', 
, u'\r\nAn interesting case has surfaced in Voronezh, Russia, where a man is suing a bank for more than 24 million Russian rubles (about $727,000) in compensation over a handcrafted document that was signed and recognized by the bank.\xa0', 
, u'\n', 
, u'\r\nA person who goes by name Dmitry Alexeev (his surname was changed ', [by the first Russian outlet to publish this story](http://abireg.ru/n_33981.html), u') said that in 2008 he received a letter from ', [Tinkoff Credit Systems](https://www.tcsbank.ru/eng/about_bank/), u'\xa0in his mailbox. It was a credit card application form with an agreement contract enclosed, much like the applications Americans receive daily from various banks working with ', **Visa**

how to get plain text only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tag.text` instead of `tag.contents`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

url = "http://www.minyanville.com/business-news/editors-pick/articles/A-Russian-Bank-Is-Sued-for/8/7/2013/id/51205"
br = mechanize.Browser()
htmltext = br.open(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for tag in soup.findAll('span',{'itemprop':'articleBody'}):
    print tag.text
```

Comment: thank you.. well theres is still something getting along at the end of the text like this, how to get rid of that too?
has so far said that the case was related to "a nonrecurrent technical issue," and it is willing to have its day in court. The next hearing will be held in September.#pagination-container {display:none;};